# How to get the index of each entry when call the map function on a map object in Dart / Flutter?

Tags: list, dictionary, dart, indexing, map-function

How to get the index of each entry in a Map<K, V> in Dart?

Specifically, can the index of each entry be printed out, if a map *function* is run on the object as shown in the below example?

*e.g. how could I print out:
MapEntry(Spring: 1) is index 0
MapEntry(Chair: 9) is index 1
MapEntry(Autumn: 3) is index 2
etc.*

```
Map<String, int> exampleMap = {"Spring" : 1, "Chair" : 9, "Autumn" : 3};

void main() {  
  exampleMap.entries.map((e) { return print(e);}).toList(); ///print each index here
      }
```

-Note: I can get the index with a List object (e.g. by using exampleList.indexOf(e)) but unsure how to do this when working with a Map object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `forEach` and a variable to track the current index:

```
Map<String, int> exampleMap = {"Spring": 1, "Chair": 9, "Autumn": 3};

void main() {
  int i = 0;
  exampleMap.forEach((key, value) {
    print(i.toString());
    print(key);
    print(value);
    i++;
  });
}
```